# What are the ways to implement speech recognition in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

So I have an Electron app that uses the web speech API (SpeechRecognition) to take the user's voice, however, it's not working. The code:

```js
if ("webkitSpeechRecognition" in window) {
  let SpeechRecognition =
    window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
  let recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

  recognition.onstart = () => {
    console.log("We are listening. Try speaking into the microphone.");
  };

  recognition.onspeechend = () => {
    recognition.stop();
  };

  recognition.onresult = (event) => {
    let transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
    console.log(transcript);
  };

  recognition.start();
} else {
  alert("Browser not supported.");
}
```

It says `We are listening...` in the console, but no matter what you say, it doesn't give an output. On the other hand, running the exact same thing in Google Chrome works and whatever I say gets console logged out with the `console.log(transcript);` part. I did some more research and it turns out that Google has recently stopped support for the Web Speech API in shell-based Chromium windows (Tmk, everything that is not Google Chrome or MS Edge), so that seems to be the reason it is not working on my Electron app.

See: [electron-speech library's end](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-speech)  [Artyom.js issue](https://github.com/sdkcarlos/artyom.js/issues/4) [another stackOverflow question regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501410/electron-not-working-with-web-speech-api)

So is there any way I can get it to work in Electron?

Comment: Hey, and if possible, maybe this question could gain enough traction to reach the companies managing these APIs and perhaps they could do something about native support on shell-based browsers. I understand the reasons they might've disabled it, but I think those should be solved in a way other than completely removing support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up doing an implementation that uses the media devices API to get the user's speech through their microphone and then sends it to a Python server using `WebSockets` which uses the audio stream with the `SpeechRecognition` pip package and returns the transcribed text to the client (Electron app).

This is what I implemented, it is way too long for a thing as simple as this, but if someone has a better suggestion, please do let me know by writing an answer.

Comment: When/If I get enough reputation, I'll put a bounty on this question, because this problem for Electron devs needs to be highlighted.

Comment: Nobody bothered to answer something better despite the bounty I placed of 100 rep. Hope this question gets some traction at some point in the future.